# CASE with 2 conditions

Tags: case

Following case statement is not working.

```
case when (product_name = 'premium' AND SUM(answered_calls)>0 then (SUM(total_duration)/60.0)/SUM(answered_calls)) else 0 end AS Duration
```

Comment: Which RDBMS? You've tagged 3 different ones

Comment: Is not working can mean several things, do you get an error code or a result that you did not expect?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if only that, but your are not closing the parenthesis correctly.

Same code with better indentation:

```
case
  when
    (product_name = 'premium' AND SUM(answered_calls)>0
  then
    (SUM(total_duration)/60.0)/SUM(answered_calls))
  else
    0
end AS Duration
```

See the problems:

```
case
  when
    (product_name = 'premium' AND SUM(answered_calls)>0
--  ^----------------------------- should close here --^
  then
    (SUM(total_duration)/60.0)/SUM(answered_calls))
--                      remove that closing one --^
  else
    0
end AS Duration
```